# Can't resolve './graphql'

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, graphql, aws-amplify

I am following this tutorial https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/react/

At this step https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react/#install-amplify-libraries after installing `aws-amplify` and `@aws-amplify/ui-react`

The moment I try and import aws-amplify like this: `import Amplify from "aws-amplify";`
I get this error in webpack:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './graphql' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'graphql.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './graphql' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 36:0-47:50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './type' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './type' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 49:0-53:205
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './language' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './language' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 55:0-101
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './execution' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './execution' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 56:0-68
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './subscription' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './subscription' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 58:0-60:675
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './validation' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './validation' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 62:0-64
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './error' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './error' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 64:0-98:42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './utilities' in '/home/ishan/amplify_start/node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/node_modules/graphql'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './utilities' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js 90:0-39 221:41-53 235:45-57 354:49-61 512:37-49 528:46-58 552:37-49
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/Providers/index.js 15:0-45 15:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib-esm/index.js 14:0-28 14:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm/index.js 27:0-45 27:0-45
 @ ./src/components/root/root_component.js 35:0-34
 @ ./src/index.js 10:0-61 11:50-63
```

Any suggestions would be very valuable.